# Google Plus Like Tableviewcell Popout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to mimic what the Google+ app does when a user clicks on a cell in the `tableView`. I realize this is a highly customized version of a tableView, but I'm wondering if anyone has any pointers on where to start. Most big features like this seem to have an opensource project where someone is already mimicking it, but I cannot find one for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CALayer *layer = cell.layer;
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-layer.bounds.size.width/4, 0, 0.0f);;

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration =0.2;
        // The block-based equivalent doesn't play well with iOS 4
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        cell.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

});
```

play with the transform you should be able to make it . use this  in the cell will display function

Answer (score 1):

The 'Feed' view looks like a UITableView with a customized UITableViewCell that has a cell.contentView of the UITableViewCell being animated with UIView `animateWithDuration:` or something in `setSelected:animated:` when the `didSelectRow`: on the 'Feed' view tableview is called.

If I were to make that customized UITableViewCell, I'd probably have two views depending on the situation: 'Setup A: the view for when it's being scrolled in the feed view' and a 'Setup B: view for when it's been clicked to show the contents of the post more indepth'

setup A would be a more normal UITableViewCell, but setup B would have the same header view of the user who posted (what you see when you're scrolling the feed view), but below that it looks like it has it's own UITableView (which animates after it's been clicked and loads all the users and their comments if there are any comments).

That's just what comes to mind initially -- Hope that's a start?